# Anonymous saveEntry?

Tags: login

I'm needing to allow users who aren't logged in to post new entries, but of course it always redirects to login. Any way I can allow saveEntry to be anonymous, preferably for a single entry type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saveEntry will always require an authenticated user with the correct permissions to post the entry, but you can use the guest entries plugin from Pixel & Tonic to allow for guest submissions :)

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries